# How do you view error details while debugging a VB6 application in Visual Studio 2010?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging, exception, vb6, attach-to-process

I'm trying to debug a legacy VB6/ASP/COM+ application using Visual Studio 2010. The COM+ DLL has been compiled with full debug information and has the corressponding .PDB files. I attach to the dllhost process of the COM+ component and during execution when an exception is thrown, I'm unable to see the details of the error in the debugger.

Typing `Err` into the **immediate window** displays `0`. Typing `Err.Description` displays `CXX0025: Error: operator needs class/struct/union`.

The **locals** window doesn't show any error or exception information. How can I view the details of a thrown exception?

---

### Update

I'm still not able to view error information or properly inspect variables and objects. I'm also using Visual Studio 2010 to debug the classic ASP pages (VBScript) parts of the application and it seems to have a full featured debugging experience, i.e. I can inspect variables and objects properly. Since classic ASP with VBScript is a close cousin of VB6 and they're both COM based, should I not be able to inspect VB6 errors, variables and objects properly too?

Comment: Do you have .pdb files for the VB6 dlls?

Comment: Yes. I can step through the source code, I can set breakpoints and the locals window shows some variables but not all. In fact objects don't seem to be viewable as they show up as type void and are not able to be expanded to show the properties like one would for a .NET object.

Answer (score 0):

You normally need an IDE for the langauge it was originally written in so VB6 for the VB6 components, VS6 for the ASP components?

Comment: My problem still stands. I understand that the VB6 IDE was designed for the VB6 language. However, my question was aimed at using Visual Studio 2010 to debug a VB6 COM+ component. I can step through the code, set and hit breakpoints perfectly fine using it. Breaking on exceptions/errors works too, but not viewing the details of it. Using VS2010, I can debug the ASP & Javascript parts of the application fully. Since ASP with VBScript is a close cousin of VB6 one would think that the debugging experience would be similarly fully featured.